# Iteration over elements of a list without redundancy; Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a search string e.g.

```
string = [1,2,3]
```

and a sample

```
sample = [[1,5,5,5,5,5],[2,5,5,5,5,5],[3,5,5,5,2],[4,5,5,5,5,5],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

Now what I want is to append the lists in the `sample` list of lists if one of their elements is in `string`

If I simply iterate over every element of the list in `sample` I get a lot of redundancy:

```
accepted = []
rejected = []

for list in sample:
    for e in list:
        if e in string:
            accepted.append(list)
        else:
            rejected.append(list)


accepted
Out: [[1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [3, 5, 5, 5, 2], [3, 5, 5, 5, 2]]

len(rejected)
Out: 23
```

What I need is to have the lists appended only once depending on whether their element is is `string` or not. E.g.,

```
accepted
Out: [[1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [3, 5, 5, 5, 2]]
rejected
Out: [[4,5,5,5,5,5],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

But can't understand how to do it in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another answer suggested a correct way based on your solution, as a more pythonic way you can preserve the `string` in a `set` and use `set.intersection` method within a list comprehension in order to get the accepted items:

```
>>> string = {1,2,3}
>>> [i for i in sample if string.intersection(i)]
[[1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [3, 5, 5, 5, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check if it was already inserted in accepted or rejected, not the best performance:

```
for list in sample:
    if list not in accepted and list not in rejected:
        for e in list:
            if e in string:
                accepted.append(list)
                break
            elif list not in rejected:
                rejected.append(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Python set to quickly determine if any of the elements in the search are present in each sample as follows:

```
search = set([1, 2, 3])
sample = [[1,5,5,5,5,5],[2,5,5,5,5,5],[3,5,5,5,2],[4,5,5,5,5,5],[5,5,5,5,5]]

accepted = []
rejected = []

for x in sample:
    if set(x) & search:
        accepted.append(x)
    else:
        rejected.append(x)

print accepted
print rejected
```

This would display:

```
[[1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [3, 5, 5, 5, 2]]
[[4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```